# How can i name cells navigation controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

```
 if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
    // EVEN
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EvenCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"EvenCell"] autorelease];
        UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

        UIColor *colour = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed: (208.0/255.f) green: (231.0/255.f) 
                                                  blue: (241.0/255.f) alpha: 1.0];
        bg.backgroundColor = colour; 
        cell.backgroundView = bg;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bg.backgroundColor;
        [bg release];
        cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

} else {
    // ODD

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OddCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"OddCell"] autorelease];
        UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

        UIColor *colour = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed: (143.0/255.f) green: (169.0/255.f) 
                                                  blue: (180.0/255.f) alpha: 1.0];
        bg.backgroundColor = colour;
        cell.backgroundView = bg;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bg.backgroundColor;
        [bg release];
        cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    }
} 

return cell;
}
```

this is my custom cells.first one is even second one is odd's.My array has 194 elements but when i run the application i can only see 10 after the 10th one it goes to first element again give me same 10 elements.Can anybody tell me what is wrong in here?

Comment: nothing wrong here... what does the `numberOfRows` return ? the mistake must be there

Comment: i checked the items array  NSLog(@"%d",[items count]); and it gives me 194 i read them from url and gives me the true number and how can i look to the number of rows

Comment: is that number returned in this method ?

Comment: no i return this in - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    NSURL *URL=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.trevesstudios.com/osman"];
 NSString *content=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    
    NSString *list=[content stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<br>"withString:@""];
 NSArray *listItems = [list componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
 array=[listItems retain];
    NSLog(@"%d",[items count]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
// EVEN
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EvenCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"EvenCell"] autorelease];
            UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];


        UIColor *colour = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed: (208.0/255.f) green: (231.0/255.f) 
                                                  blue: (241.0/255.f) alpha: 1.0];
        bg.backgroundColor = colour; 
        cell.backgroundView = bg;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bg.backgroundColor;
        [bg release];
    }
        cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


} else {
    // ODD

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OddCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"OddCell"] autorelease];
        UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

        UIColor *colour = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed: (143.0/255.f) green: (169.0/255.f) 
                                                  blue: (180.0/255.f) alpha: 1.0];
        bg.backgroundColor = colour;
        cell.backgroundView = bg;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bg.backgroundColor;
        [bg release];
    }
        cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


  } 

  return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for your view to display the correct number of rows, make sure, the `-(NSUInteger)tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:(NSUInteger)section` returns the correct number. (in your case, you should return `[items count]`).

Comment: thanks vince for your patience and help lanc solution is true.

Comment: i put the cell.textLabel.text = [items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator; code into the if statement.He takes out that part.